# How to extract end of URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have URLs in the form:

> serverName/app/image/thumbnail/2012/4/23/1335228884300/bb65efd50ade4b3591dcf7f4c693042b

Where `serverName` is the domain name of the server.

I would like to write a JS function that accepts one of these URLs and returns the very last (right-most) forward-slash-delimited string. So if the URL above was passed into the function, it would return "`bb65efd50ade4b3591dcf7f4c693042b`";.

```
function getImageDirectoryByFullURL(url) {
    // ... Not sure how to define regexp to delimit on forward slashes,
    // or how to start searching from end of string.
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[split by slashes `/`, pop off the last and return it](http://jsfiddle.net/H2GE6/)

```
function getImageDirectoryByFullURL(url){
    return url.split('/').pop()
}

//a step by step breakdown
function getImageDirectoryByFullURL(url){
    url = url.split('/'); //url = ["serverName","app",...,"bb65efd50ade4b3591dcf7f4c693042b"]
    url = url.pop();      //url = "bb65efd50ade4b3591dcf7f4c693042b"
    return url;           //return "bb65efd50ade4b3591dcf7f4c693042b"
}
```

what this does is split the url per `/` and returns an array of values in between, but not including, the slashes. then, since what's returned by `split()` is an array, we can use `pop()` to pop off the last item and return it.

Comment: Good example of doing OP wants, not what he thinks he wants :P

Comment: How would I pop off that last index in the returned array?

Comment: @AdamTannon `split()` returns an array which `pop()` can use. `pop()` returns the last item in the array provided by `split()`, and thus is what's returned by the whole function.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, `substr()` *might* be faster than `split()`. Not 100% sure.

```
function getImageDirectoryByFullURL(url){
    return url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
}
```

---

Edit: I forgot, you don't need to include the extra length parameter. Without passing that in you just get a `substr` to the end of the string, which is what is desired. While this solution is admittedly a little uglier than Joseph's answer, it is twice as fast in Chrome and something like fives times as fast in Firefox.

Comment: I doubt the speed difference is large enough to matter. Your solution and the one proposed by Joseph are both valid (though I personally prefer his because it's shorter and more succinct).

Comment: Yep. Just thought I'd propose a different method of doing it, because... well, just because. =]

Comment: +1, great alternative, just add a +1 here `lastIndexOf("/")+1` to remove the first `/`

Comment: amazingly, this is way much faster that the pop solution http://jsperf.com/popvslastindex

Comment: @ajax333221: Wow, thanks for the test. I suspected it would be faster; just didn't know how much faster. I'm betting it's because with the `split()` solution you have the overhead of creating the array and then calling the `pop()` function on it, whereas `str.substr()` just immediately returns the requested string.

Answer (score 3):

To make it a little more robust and allow for the possible presence of a trailing slash, hash tags or query parameters on the URL:

```
function getImageDirectoryByFullURL(url){
    url = url.replace(/#[^#]+$/, "").replace(/\?[^\?]+$/, "").replace(/\/$/, "");
    return url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
```

And a working demo with a bunch of test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/akVVf/

Comment: @ElliotBonneville— +1 for the ridiculous +1. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the regexes are ridiculous.  `/#[^#]+$/` matches from the last `#` to the end of the string.  Same for `/\?[^\?]+$/` with a `?`.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no sensible regular expression versions, consider:

```
return url.replace(/^.*\//,'');
```

Comment: Better hope the URL doesn't have a trailing slash on it.

Comment: The OP can sort that, the requirement was "…the very last (right-most) forward-slash-delimited string".

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try something like this, getting the same result.

```
function getImageUrl( url){
    var result = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: See my answer; also keep in mind that Javascript functions are case-sensitive (`LastIndexOf` should be `lastIndexOf`), and you'll want `lastIndexOf("/") + 1` to avoid including the extra "/" at the beginning of the string.